# Add Array of JSONobject data to mysql

Tags: php, json, android-volley

I have to send an array of JSON object from Android app via Volley and have to process it in the back-end PHP, in order to insert them into the relevant table. 
In the server side, the array is being received successfully (I convert the array as a string in the app code and then sending it as a String). 
But I'm unable to find the error in my code. In case if my method is wrong, it will be grateful if you can suggest me a proper/efficient way.

```
This is the string being received in the server side : 

[
  {
    "product": 1451,
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "product": 2704,
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "product": 2705,
    "qty": 1
  }
]
```

> code is

```
  case "sales_items": //print_r($_POST);
                            $invoice = $_POST['invoice']; 
                            $sales_items = $_POST['sales_items'];

                        foreach($sales_items as $item){
                            mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO app_sales_items(invoice,product,qty) 
                            VALUES('$invoice','".$item["product"]."','".$item["qty"]."')")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        }

                        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0) {  
                                $response['status'] = true;
                            }
                            else $response['status'] = false;

                        echo json

_encode($response);         
                    break;
```

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements rather than directly inserting your values into your query string.

Comment: I see 0% relation to `android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do json_decode to get data as array

```
$sales_items = '[{"product":1451,"qty":1},{"product":2704,"qty":1},
       {"product":2705,"qty":1}]';
     $data = json_decode($sales_items, true);
     foreach($data as $item) {

       //ur code here
      }
```

use prepared statements to save data

demo link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55773f703a27d76fbead654af6554c8c6fabb401